# Jain SIP get user name

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I need to get the extension number from the "From header", I have tried everything but nothing worked.

Even tried to do:

```
byte[] raw = req.getRawContent();
```

And manually find the From and the number, But that returned null

What am I doing wrong? How to get that number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `FromHeader` and then extract the information you need from it.  For instance, if the extension is the user part of the URI:

```
FromHeader fromHeader = (FromHeader) req.getHeader("From");
Address fromAddress = fromHeader.getAddress();
URI fromURI = fromAddress.getURI();
if (fromURI.isSipURI()) {
  SipURI fromSipURI = (SipURI) fromURI;
  extension = fromSipURI.getUser();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that did the job. You saved me couple of hours

Answer (score 1):

Did you saw the javadoc?

The method getRawContent() return a message content as a raw byte array, **or null if no content is set**

Can you explain again your question? Maybe I can help you.

Comment: I see, this don't return the packet as byte array, but the message content. SDP for example